# How do I create a PDE organization?

Tags: partner-portal

Previously I was able to login to the Salesforce Partner Portal using a @partnerforce.com login and then using the 'Create a test org' option in the quick links.

How do I now accomplish the above?

Answer (score 0):

I understand the Partner Portal is now depriciated and that creation of test orgs is now handled through the environment hub for which you have to submit a case to request access.